# My encryption is skipping over lowercase letters

Tags: java, encryption, javafx

For instance if I submit the string "TEST3>" to the program it will give you "#4$%DO" back, and if you reencrypt "#4$%DO" it will give you "TEST3>" back.  However, if you input "TEsT" it will give you "#4%" back(notice it skips over the 's' character) and if you reencrypt that with the program you get "TERQ" back because it is missing the 's'.  Can anyone enlighten me on why?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package cryptomatic2;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Zach
 */
public class Cryptomatic2 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        String key = "wq";
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        Label inputLabel = new Label("Input");
        TextArea input = new TextArea();
        input.setMinSize(400, 200);
        Button encrypt = new Button("Encrypt");
        encrypt.setMinSize(100, 100);
        Button decrypt = new Button("Decrypt");
        decrypt.setMinSize(100, 100);
        Label outputLabel = new Label("Output");
        TextArea output = new TextArea();
        output.setMinSize(400, 200);

        root.add(inputLabel, 0, 0);
        root.add(input, 0, 1);
        root.add(encrypt, 0, 2);
        root.add(decrypt, 1, 2);
        root.add(outputLabel, 0, 3);
        root.add(output, 0, 4);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 800);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Cryptomatic");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        encrypt.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                String source = input.getText();
                String newString = "";
                if(source.length() % 2 != 0){
                    source = source + " ";
                }
                for(int i = 0; i < source.length(); i+=2){
                    char value1 = source.charAt(i);
                    char value2 = source.charAt(i+1);
                    char key1 = key.charAt(0);
                    char key2 = key.charAt(1);                        
                    int newValue1 = value1 ^ key1;
                    int newValue2 = value2 ^ key2;
                    String encrypted1 = Character.toString((char) newValue1);
                    String encrypted2 = Character.toString((char) newValue2);
                    newString = newString + encrypted1 + encrypted2;
                }
                output.setText(newString);
            }
        });  
    }



    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Works okay for me, with your test data and with `"This is a Test"`. `TEsT` does not generate `#4%`, but `#4 %`, there's a unrenderable character (where the space is) in the `String` (ascii character 4), you either need to limit your encryption to generate characters within the displayable range or present the string in a better manner

Comment: @MadProgrammer what do you mean by present the string in a better manner?

Comment: Something that will display the missing character, me be using the unicode character "4" for example: ; which would display the `String` as `#4%`, or displaying them has hex characters instead, or what ever...